# How to Sum Array element int Dart

Tags: arrays, dart, sum

> I have an array looking like this

```
final value = [
  {
  'category': 'Social Life', 
  'data': [
        {'amount': 2000, 'content': 'thanks'}
        ]
  }, 
  {
  'category': 'Food', 
  'data': [
        {'amount': 2000, 'content': 'thanks'}, 
        {'amount': 2000, 'content': 'thanks'}
        ]
   }
]
```

I want to calculate the amount of each category using the `fold()` method, but I don't know how to implement it

> i want them look like this in my new variable

```
    final newValue = [
      {
      'category': 'Social Life', 
      'amount': //the amount for 'Social Life' category,  
      }, 
      {
      'category': 'Food', 
      'amount': //the amount for 'Food' category, 
      }
    ]
```

Comment: How to you want the result to be stored? Also, what type are e.g. variable name `category`? Is it a String key or something else?

Comment: I just want to save it in my new variable, yes the key is string

Comment: Ok, but do you want the sum of all the `amount` values in `value` or one sum for each `category`? If the last, do you want a `Map<String, int>` where the key is the category name and value is the sum of this category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
void main() {
  final value = [
    {
      'category': 'Social Life',
      'data': [
        {'amount': 2000, 'content': 'thanks'}
      ]
    },
    {
      'category': 'Food',
      'data': [
        {'amount': 2000, 'content': 'thanks'},
        {'amount': 2000, 'content': 'thanks'}
      ]
    }
  ];

  print(combineData(value));
  // [{category: Social Life, amount: 2000}, {category: Food, amount: 4000}]
}

List<Map<String, Object>> combineData(List<Map<String, Object>> value) => value
    .map((entry) => {
          'category': entry['category'],
          'amount': (entry['data'] as List<Map<String, Object>>).fold<int>(
              0, (prev, element) => prev + (element['amount'] as int))
        })
    .toList();
```